# Kernel Panic - not syncing: attempted to kill init (for VM image from a physical machine)

Tags: centos, redhat, kernel, grub

I had a CentOS 5.4 x86_64 machine where I imaged the primary partition with the following command so that I could run it in a VM on my local machine for testing.

```
#dd bs=1024 count=10482412 if/dev/sda of/mnt/storage/sda.img
```

Then I converted the image on my local machine with the command:

```
#VBoxManage convertdd sda.img sda.vmdk --format VMDK --variant Standard
```

I created a new VM and loaded this image as the hard disk. I booted with a Cent OS 5.4 x85_64 installation DVD into rescue mode. I chrooted into the image and reinstalled grub by doing the following:

```
#mount --bind /proc /mnt/disks/sda1/proc
#mount --bind /dev /mnt/disks/sda1/dev
#mount --bind /sys /mnt/disks/sda1/sys
#chroot /mnt/disks/sda1
#grub-install hd0
```

Then I rebooted the VM and grub displayed 3 selections. I've tried all 3 of them and I get a kernel panic every time. It starts booting and then I get the following message from each of the 3 choices:
"Kernel Panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!"

I'm not sure what to do to get it to boot properly...

Comment: My first guess would be that something is off in translating the drive geometry to an image, but I'm not a drive expert. If you run Testdisk from a boot disc on the image drive, does it find anything it can repair? In the advanced tools it may even see whether the contents of the drive are readable.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the initrd image is not valid, there must be a problem with the paths when the image makes the switchroot.
A common cause is that all drivers are not loaded in the initrd and thus the hard drive is not detected. Can you provide:

a) the grub.conf output

b) the content of the /etc/modprobe.conf on your virtual disk
?
The remedy I would suggest is to repeat your

```
#mount --bind /proc /mnt/disks/sda1/proc
#mount --bind /dev /mnt/disks/sda1/dev
#mount --bind /sys /mnt/disks/sda1/sys
#chroot /mnt/disks/sda1
```

operation and then run mkinitrd from chrooted environnement, but with a fixed alias scsi_hostadapter xxxx 
line in your modprobe.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Does the VM host definitely support 64-bit guests? VMWare at least doesn't support 64-bit guests on older AMD CPUs and Intel CPUs that are not VT-capable (and some fairly recent Intel chips do not have VT). You can check for support using Intel's list at http://ark.intel.com/VTList.aspx or by using a tool like [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html).

I would expect the boot to fail very early on if this is the cause of your problem though. It would be a good idea to indicate in your question the last few things that were displayed before the error.

Comment: I am running a brand new Macbook Pro 13", so I believe the CPU is a 2.4GHz Core2Duo P8600